# recursively find parents in JSON array backward connect by prev value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

```
[
  {
    "secCode": 2,
    "secName": "GENERAL NURSING CARE SECTION",
    "prevSec": 0,

  },
  {
    "secCode": 1,
    "secName": "CRITICAL CARE NURSING SECTION",
    "prevSec": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "secCode": 3,
        "secName": "OPERATION THEATRE",
        "prevSec": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "secCode": 5,
            "secName": "MAIN OPERATION THEATRE",
            "prevSec": 3,
            "estCode": 152,

          },
          {
            "secCode": 6,
            "secName": "DAY CARE DT SERVICE",
            "prevSec": 3,

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "secCode": 4,
        "secName": "CRITICAL CARE SERVICES",
        "prevSec": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "secCode": 675,
            "secName": "Test",
            "prevSec": 4,
            "children": [
              {
                "secCode": 676,
                "secName": "Test1",
                "prevSec": 675,

              },
              {
                "secCode": 677,
                "secName": "Test 2",
                "prevSec": 675,

              },
              {
                "secCode": 678,
                "secName": "Test 3",
                "prevSec": 675,

              },
              {
                "secCode": 679,
                "secName": "Test 4",
                "prevSec": 675,

              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "secCode": 7,
            "secName": "ACUTE CARE",
            "prevSec": 4,

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the tree json tree structure. Here each node connected to its parent using prevSec value recursively backward. 
For secCode 7 its parents tree will be [7, 4, 1] - connected by secCode = prevSec.
For secCode 679 its parents will be [679, 675, 4, 1]
For secCode  2 its parents will be [2]

I had tried this solution which is partial

```
 getParent(arr, childSecCode) {

        if (childSecCode == 0) {
          return;
        } else {
          let val = arr.find(item => {
           childSecCode === item.secCode;
          });
          if (val) {
            //arr.find(item => childSecCode == item.secCode).showChildren = true;
           /*  if(check ==0)
            arr.find(item => childSecCode == item.secCode).className = "selected"; */
            this.getParent(arr, val.prevSec);
          }
        }
      }
```

This will not work as find doesn't check for children.

How can I achieve the desired result.

Comment: So, for a given secCode, you need to find the path in this object. Correct?

Comment: Why is this tagged with angular? I don't see anything in the question that needs that specification.

Comment: Why *"for 7 its parents tree will be [7, 4, 3, 1]"* when the parent of 4 is 1 and not 3? What is the logic for getting 3 in there? Same with the other example...

Comment: Why do you pass *two* arguments to `getParent`? Why not just the subtree of which the root is the item of which you need the parent(s)? It would be good to know in which context you need this method. I am convinced that could be designed better. It would also be good to see the class where this happens, and where the overall data structure is stored in there, so we can access it from the root.

Comment: @trincot in result 3 is added by mistake. I had removed that  and question updated.

Comment: @trincot Q) why 2 arguments ? A) one Is the array and other is the last parents prevSec value.

Comment: Did any answer from bellow helped you? If not, tag me in your reply and I'll add the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a search through the whole tree whenever you need this, it is better to first preprocess your tree, so that you can find any node (object) directly, in constant time, given its `secCode`.

You can create a `Map` for that connection between `secCode` and node:

```js
// Creates a map which is keyed by secCode, and for a secCode provides 
//   the corresponding node from the tree
function createMap(tree) {
    let map = new Map;
    
    function recur(node) {
        map.set(node.secCode, node);
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recur);
    }
    
    tree.forEach(recur);
    return map;
}

// Uses the map to walk up the tree
function getParents(secCode, map) {
    let parents = [];
    while (secCode) {
        parents.push(secCode);
        let node = map.get(secCode);
        secCode = node.prevSec;
    }
    return parents;
}

// The tree from the question:
let tree = [{"secCode": 2,"secName": "GENERAL NURSING CARE SECTION","prevSec": 0,},{"secCode": 1,"secName": "CRITICAL CARE NURSING SECTION","prevSec": 0,"children": [{"secCode": 3,"secName": "OPERATION THEATRE","prevSec": 1,"children": [{"secCode": 5,"secName": "MAIN OPERATION THEATRE","prevSec": 3,"estCode": 152,},{"secCode": 6,"secName": "DAY CARE DT SERVICE","prevSec": 3,}]},{"secCode": 4,"secName": "CRITICAL CARE SERVICES","prevSec": 1,"children": [{"secCode": 675,"secName": "Test","prevSec": 4,"children": [{"secCode": 676,"secName": "Test1","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 677,"secName": "Test 2","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 678,"secName": "Test 3","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 679,"secName": "Test 4","prevSec": 675,}]},{"secCode": 7,"secName": "ACUTE CARE","prevSec": 4,}]}]}];
// Preprocessing
let map = createMap(tree);
// Example calls:
console.log(getParents(7, map));
console.log(getParents(679, map));
```

Note that the tree in your example does not have 4 as a child of 3 as your examples suggest -- 4 is a child of 1.

If you have a class, you can of course create that map in its constructor and assign it to a property:

```js
class Tree {
    constructor(data) {
        this.map = new Map;

        const recur = (node) => {
            this.map.set(node.secCode, node);
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recur);
        }

        data.forEach(recur);
    }
    getParents(secCode) {
        let parents = [];
        while (secCode) {
            parents.push(secCode);
            secCode = this.map.get(secCode).prevSec;
        }
        return parents;
    }
}

// The tree from the question:
let data = [{"secCode": 2,"secName": "GENERAL NURSING CARE SECTION","prevSec": 0,},{"secCode": 1,"secName": "CRITICAL CARE NURSING SECTION","prevSec": 0,"children": [{"secCode": 3,"secName": "OPERATION THEATRE","prevSec": 1,"children": [{"secCode": 5,"secName": "MAIN OPERATION THEATRE","prevSec": 3,"estCode": 152,},{"secCode": 6,"secName": "DAY CARE DT SERVICE","prevSec": 3,}]},{"secCode": 4,"secName": "CRITICAL CARE SERVICES","prevSec": 1,"children": [{"secCode": 675,"secName": "Test","prevSec": 4,"children": [{"secCode": 676,"secName": "Test1","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 677,"secName": "Test 2","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 678,"secName": "Test 3","prevSec": 675,},{"secCode": 679,"secName": "Test 4","prevSec": 675,}]},{"secCode": 7,"secName": "ACUTE CARE","prevSec": 4,}]}]}];
// Preprocessing
let tree = new Tree(data);
// Example calls:
console.log(tree.getParents(7));
console.log(tree.getParents(679));
```

Comment: let tree = new Tree(data); // Tree is not defined error

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The snippets do not produce this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively traverse your data structure like this.

```
getParent(arr, childSecCode){
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    if(item.secCode === childSecCode)
      return item.prevSec; // found item
    if(item.children) {
      const prevSec = getParent(item.children, childSecCode);
      if(prevSec) return prevSec;
    }
  }
}
```

This method is using a depth first algorithm.